# Microsoft ClickOnce Deployment with SFTP possible ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, c#

I know that we could use FTP, Remote Website and Desktop to deploy our applications. 
I would like to know if anyone could suggest how to use SFTP instead?

Are there any plugins that exist for this?